# Laravel - dateformat validation not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

My code:

```
$data['from'] = '2020-03-20 20:30:00';
$data['to'] = '2020-03-21 00:45:00';
$validity = \Validator::make($data, [
    'from' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'],
    'to' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s']
]);

// This if gets true, and the error message is:
```

> The to does not match the format Y-m-d H:i:s

```
if($validity->fails()) {
    dd($validity->errors());
}
```

and amazingly when I change `00:45:00` to `01:45:00` it doesn't get inside that if. How can I fix it?

Comment: What locale is this on? It's passing for me just fine

Comment: Asia/Tehran....

Comment: 2020-03-21 00:45:00 is not a valid time in Tehran since daylight savings moves clocks from 00:00 to 01:00 so it never occurs

Comment: O' My GUSH!! Yeah you made my Night :)) Should I delete this message because of simplicity?

Comment: I'd say leave question up and let @apokryfos answer it.

Comment: I think I'll post the comment as an answer. Maybe someone else runs into it. It's actually a weird thing to encounter for most people since the date and time of DST is not the typical one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your locale is set up to be `Asia/Tehran` the time `2020-03-21 00:45:00` is actually not valid. According to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran:

> Saturday, 21 March 2020, 00:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
>   Saturday, 21 March 2020, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead.

This means that times between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00 never occur.  Since the Laravel date validator internally uses PHP's date parsing then that parsing fails and the error is raised. If you want to check only if a date is a given format ignoring any daylight savings quirks then you can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to temporarily set the locale to one that does not observe daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$validity = \Validator::make($data, [
    'from' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'to' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'
]);
```